# Is there any difference between LiveCD Upgrade and Update Manage Upgrade

Tags: updates, dist-upgrade

Are there any differences between an upgrade from a LiveCD or the software options in the system like Update Manager?

Just to make sure that when a user updates from a LiveCD, he/she gets the same as doing it via Update Manager included in the system.

Comment: What is "upgrade from a LiveCD"? Never heard of this, apart from version upgrade, e.q. 12.04 to 12.10. Which is very different from what `apt-get upgrade` does.

Comment: When you insert a LiveCD to an already installed Ubuntu computer, in the installation process it mentions if you want to upgrade from  the previous version.

Comment: Update Manager, apt-get and aptitude are all used to update packages within the same version of Ubuntu. You'll never transition from, say, 12.04 to 12.10 by doing `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. The process of upgrading from one Ubuntu release to another is called "release upgrade" and is quite different. Maybe you need to edit the question to mention `do-release-upgrade` instead of `apt-get` and `aptitude`

Comment: @Sergey - Not what I mean, The LiveCD has an option to upgrade from a previous version to the next. Same when using Update Manager that an option appears in the upper part showing the new version and if you want to upgrade to it. For apt-get/aptitude what I meant was `update-manager -c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any difference between LiveCD Upgrade and Update Manage
>   Upgrade?

**Yes**,When you upgrade from update manager all the apps including third party apps will be upgraded, If you upgraded using live cd, most of the additionally installed packages will  be removed, you have to install all the packages again

Comment: Could you clarify on "most of the additionally installed packages will be removed"? I was under impression that "LiveCD upgrade" just removes everything except `/home` from the partition and then just makes a normal install onto that partition, which means that the "upgraded" machine will be no different from a vanilla install, apart from the contents of `/home`. However, I never tried this upgrade method, so I'm curious - what settings/applications are preserved and what are not?

Comment: @Sergy : yup everything except apps installed in /home and apps installed from source code or any other non dpkg methods will be removed, (from my experiance)